# How to edit Flask-plus default swagger-UI text

Tags: python, rest, flask, swagger, flask-restplus

I am developing a simple rest api that only has two Get methods so far. It's working fine etc, and looks pretty great when I navigate to the url thanks to the built in swagger documentation.

However I do not actually see a yaml or json file anywhere. How do I change the title and default values as shown in the screenshot? Hopefully it's possible without making a whole separate yaml or json doc?

I don't actually want to change the design at all. I only want to edit the text a little.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the title when creating the API:

```
api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='Your API Name', 
          description='A more complete description')
```

You set the namespace to something other than **default** by creating a namespace:

```
ns = api.namespace('not-default', 
                   description='Whatever your namespace is')
```

Then you create your routes in the appropriate namespace:

```
@ns.route(...)
```

This is a handy way to group your APIs. See the [Full Example](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html) for help if needed.

Comment: To add on to that... your answer prompted me to this bug tracker: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/460 . 

Thanks for your answer

Comment: I had to add api.namespaces.clear() before setting the ns variable. Works nicely!

Answer (score -1):

I've found one more solution to rename this defaul namespace:

```
app = Flask(__name__)    
api = Api(app, default="Your text", default_label="Your text for description")
```

[image]